# Register-SSMTaskWithMaintenanceWindow Cmdlet for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-sdk, aws-powershell

I have following CMD. $newtarget is a new maintenance window defined before.

```
$newtask = Register-SSMTaskWithMaintenanceWindow -Windowid $newmw -ServiceRoleArn "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx" -MaxConcurrency 1 -MaxError 1 -TaskArn "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" -Target @{ Key="WindowTargetIds";Values="$newtarget"} -TaskType "RUN_COMMAND" -Priority 10
```

How can I put the Powershell Code inside that I want to register within this task? Has anyone an idea? I looked over the API but do not know how. It doesnt matter if I download the ps1 and execute it (path inside task) or the whole code itself.

I was thinking of something like:

```
$parameters = @{}
$parameterValues = New-Object Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model.MaintenanceWindowTaskParameterValueExpression
$parameterValues.Values = <the PS Code in some way>
parameters.Add("Commands", $parameterValues)
```

Thx for any help.

Comment: I tried it this way and the Commands Input is empty. Even if I write $parameterValues.Values = @("Test") or else it doesnt put anything in.

Answer (score 1):

I see some more options in the command, against what is in the documentation of the command, for example: TaskInvocationParameters_RunCommand_Parameters

Check below example, it would require you to create $parameters and assign to TaskInvocationParameters_RunCommand_Parameters - in case of RUN_COMMAND type. There are similar options available for other types (Automation, Lambda..)

```
#create command parameters
$parameters = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]]::new()
$parameters.Add("commands",@("ipconfig","dir env:\computername"))
$parameters.Add("executionTimeout",@(3600))

Register-SSMTaskWithMaintenanceWindow 
    -WindowId $mw 
    -ServiceRoleArn $myIAMRole
    -MaxConcurrency 1 
    -MaxError 1 
    -TaskType RUN_COMMAND 
    -TaskArn "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" 
    -Target @{Key="WindowTargetIds";Values=$targetTo} 
    -Priority 10 
    -TaskInvocationParameters_RunCommand_Parameters $parameters 
    -Name "new-world"
```

Comment: Hi, I know this option but never used it on the cmd. the documentation of the API didnt mention. I tried it and it works. where did you see it? Thx very much. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Register-SSMTaskWithMaintenanceWindow.html)

Comment: @ghraz0r I actually reached doing reverse journey after creating one from the console - like this: $taskPS = Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowTask -WindowId $mw -WindowTaskId $TaskID --

Comment: pretty smart ;)